# How to correct zero cell counts for odds ratio calculations when variable has >2 categories

Tags: categorical-data, estimation, binomial-distribution, odds-ratio, contingency-tables

I am trying to calculate odds ratios for several univariate models with a binomial outcome.

The problem is, for some of my variables, I have at least 1 zero count cell.

It seems that the Haldane correction (0.5 is added to all cells of the contingency table) is commonly used when there is a zero count cell for a 2x2 contingency table. However, some of my variables have more than 2 levels.

Can I apply the Haldane correction for my variables with >2 categorical levels? Or, is there an alternate recommendation to fix this problem?